# Android carousel 3rd party library

Tags: android

Are there any 3rd party carousel widgets that I can reuse in android?

I am looking for something like this http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel but for android.

At the moment I've developed it my self extending View class, but it becamse more complex to add new features, so I am just wondering if I can reuse some code

Answer (score 2):

1. Linderdaum Engine (http://www.linderdaum.com) has a working implementation of the 3D "carousel" widget.

Here it is in action: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Pc5e489SIY

The engine runs on both android and windows and it is written in C++.

The basic idea, just to get you started.

The sequence of images is rendered as a sequence of 3d quads. The vertices of each quad are placed on the "direction curves". For the "coverflow" appearance we use the exp(-t*t) curve. 't' is the current viewing parameter.

1. For the simpler effects one might use this http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

This one is written in Java by Neil Davies.