# How to create 3d animation like this in Android?

Tags: android, animation, 3d, android-custom-view

I need to create a custom view in Android that does this animation:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=owDzB4Q95fM#t=48s

can anyone point me what views and classes should I use? any tutorial for a similar or close idea?

Comment: This might be useful also 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728146/android-carousel-3rd-party-library/10325405#10325405

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advice you to see these links

[Interfuser Coverflow v1](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html)

[Interfuser coverflow v2](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html)

[open source coverflow project](http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/)

hope this what you ae looking for

Comment: is there an apache license solution , similar to this one?